# Isomorphism between locally free shaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I would like to ask the following question. I think it is pretty naive, but here we go. Let us suppose that we have a locally ringed space $(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})$ (or a scheme) and two locally free $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-modules $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ of the same rank $r$. Let
$$f:\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$$
a morphism of $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-modules. If the above morphism is an isomorphism, then, the induced one between the top exterior powers:
$$\land^{r}\mathcal{F}\to\land^{r}\mathcal{G}$$
is an isomorphism. Is it the converse true? I´m not sure about this statement. On the other hand, I would like to ask if every morphism between invertible $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-modules is identically zero or an isomorphism. It is true if both sheaves are $\mathcal{O}_{X}$, but I am no longer sure about the veracity of the statement if we take arbitrary invertible modules.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Q1. Yes, if $\det(f)$ is invertible, then so is $f$. This follows from the same statement for matrices.

Q2. No. A morphism $\mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X$ is a function, and it is not true in general that every non-zero function is invertible. E.g., take $X = \mathbb{A}^1$ and $f = x$ (the coordinate).